# Displaying a modal from Textbox_TextChanged call with AutoPostback = True. (Help, modal not displaying)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that I would like to display upon textchanged event of a textbox. I understand that I need call the modal with a function, since textbox doesnt have like the data-toggle thing u can bind to button. Can anybody teach me how can I call a modal from a textbox_textchanged?

Here's my textbox's attributes.

```
<asp:TextBox class="input-material" ID="barcodeInput" runat="server" Placeholder="Scan Your Matric Card" Text="" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

My modal design:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <strong><asp:Label ID="welcomeerror" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></strong>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:Image ID="avatar" runat="server" class ="img-fluid rounded-circle" ImageUrl="~/GUIs/img/imgDefault.png"/></div>

        <div>
            <p>Student Name  :</p>
        </div> 
        <asp:Label ID="studentName" runat="server" Text="Student Name" class="label-material"></asp:Label>
        <div>
            <p>Matric Number  :</p>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="matricNo" runat="server" Text="Matric No" class="label-material"></asp:Label>
        <div>
            <p>Attendance Date/Time  :</p>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="attendanceDateTime" runat="server" Text="Time Attended" class="label-material"></asp:Label>
    </div>            
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <strong><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Thank You For Attending This Activity"></asp:Label></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you want to display a div on `OnTextChanged`?

Comment: Yes, a div, of modal class.

Comment: Have you tried to simply use the `div`'s visibility to show/hide it? Basically something like `mymodal.Visible = true`

Comment: Two ways of doing this: 1) Include the html for modal in your main page and use js to show it on textchange. 2) do not include it in your main page and when the textchange happens, using ajax get the modal and inject it into the parent. Then do not get it the next time since it has been fetched. 2nd approach is more complex.

Comment: I found a script to fire the said (1) method, but I haven't got a clue on how to include it inside my html. 

$('#<%= barcodeinput.ClientID %>').change(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }); 

@CodingYoshi

Comment: Just put that within `&lt;script&gt;$(function() { //your code here });&lt;/script&gt;`